# Article selection while creating a mailing?

Tags: joomla

I'm using Civicrm into my Joomla 3.4.5 site.
Is it possible to select some articles into my joomla article's archive and insert them directly into a civicrm mail while i create a new mailing within the mailing template creation process?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Content Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/content-tokens) extensions and see if it fulfill your needs, if that doesn't suits you can always create your own tokens, have a look at @Coleman's [post](https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit).